# Draw 15Km radius around point in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw a a circle of 15 KM radius around a point on Google Maps by using Android. 
In Android we only have MapView and MapViewController. How can I implement the drawCircle funciton provided in [Google Map Circle](http://esa.ilmari.googlepages.com/circle.htm/) example in Android.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement [Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay).
And draw circle like in [FixedMylocationOverlay](http://geobeagle.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1086/trunk/GeoBeagle/di/com/google/code/geobeagle/activity/map/GeoMapActivity.java) in draw method.